# disable dynamic proxy in Entity framework globally

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Please how can I disable dynamic proxies for all entities created in Entity Framework 5.

Currently, I am setting this  `espEntities.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;` in every instance of a `DbContext` is there a way I can do this for current and future models as a one time task.

Thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**Method 1**

If you have an EDMX model, a partial class is created. Use that and in the `OnContextCreated` you can disable `ProxyCreationEnabled`

```
public partial class MyModelContainer
{
    public void OnContextCreated()
    {
        this.Configuration.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

Edit the model.tt file. Find the line containing something like this:

```
partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#> : DbContext
```

And add in

```
this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

**Method 3**

If you are not using an EDMX file, do it in your context constructor: (assuming your context is called EspEntities)

```
public class EspEntities : DbContext
{
   public EspEntities()
   {
      Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Hello David,I assume the context constructor in this case is found in the model.context.cs. However, if this is the case, it creates an issue if the EDMX model is updated and the changes will be overwritten?

Comment: Proxy creation != lazy loading. Lazy loading does require proxy creation, but disabling it doesn't disable proxy creation. Proxy creation is also required (and used) for e.g. change tracking. Your original option is good, as long as you either make the change in the template (instead of the template's output), or add it to a new file (the class should be a partial class, so it can be extended in other files).

Comment: Thanks once again David for the quick response...however, this just disables lazyloading and the dynamic proxies are still generated...?

Comment: @hvd you mean I should extend the model.context.cs by creating a new partial class and override the existing constructor? in between any good tip on making this change in the model.tt file?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, another change made.

Comment: @user989865 To clarify, what I meant was a mix of method 1 and method 3 in this answer: `partial class EspEntities { public EspEntities() { Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; } }`. But it only works if the templates create a partial class (IIRC, they do) and don't create a constructor (but this I'm not sure of). Regardless, modifying the template (method 2 in this answer) gives the same results.