# How can I query different tables dynamically with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dbcontext

So I'm not sure if you can do this or not, but I would like to avoid using SQL strings if I can.  What I would like to do with Linq/DbContexts is the following that can be done easily with SQL:

```
string sql = "UPDATE " + tableName + " SET Status=0 WHERE Id=" + formId.ToString();
```

I can easily put this into a loop where tableName and formId are given dynamically and execute no problem.

I have multiple DbContexts, so I don't know of any way to do something like:

```
var db = new *dynamicallyChosenContext*()

var query = from p in db.*dynamicallyChosenAlso*
            where p.Id == formId
            select p;

foreach (var result in query)
{
    result.Status = 0;
}

db.SaveChanges()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Gross... I don't want to do that, just figured there should be a way to do this since it's so easy with SQL.

Comment: All your EF entities have the `Id` and the `Status` properties? Your problem is less related to LINQ itself, and more to the fact that C# is a statically typed language - you can't (easily) do what you want without having some base type representing the common properties that you want to use in your generic query.

Comment: Also, having many `DbContext`s does not help, even considering that [there are ways of getting the current context from a given entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25230024/get-dbcontext-from-entity-in-entity-framework).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of working code that can update different tables at runtime from different contexts without using reflection.

```
namespace DemoContexts
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;


    public interface IThing
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        int Status { get; set; }
    }

    public class FirstPersonThing : IThing
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Foo { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondPersonThing : IThing
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Status { get; set; }
        public string Bar { get; set; }
    }

    public class FirstContext : DbContext
    {
        public FirstContext() : base("FirstContext") { }
        public DbSet<FirstPersonThing> MyThings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SecondPersonThing> YourThings { get; set; }
    }

    public class SecondContext : DbContext
    {
        public SecondContext() : base("SecondContext") { }
        public DbSet<FirstPersonThing> MyThings { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SecondPersonThing> YourThings { get; set; }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int contextType = 1;
            int thingType = 1;

            DbContext db = RunTimeCreatedContext(contextType);
            IQueryable<IThing> collection = RunTimeCreatedCollection(db, thingType);

            UpdateRuntimeDeterminedThings(db, collection, 1);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void UpdateRuntimeDeterminedThings(DbContext db, 
                                               IQueryable<IThing> collection, 
                                               int formId)
        {
            var querySet = collection.Where(p => p.Id == formId).ToList();
            foreach (var result in querySet)
            {
                result.Status = 0;
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        static DbContext RunTimeCreatedContext(int contextType)
        {
            if (contextType == 0)
            {
                return new FirstContext();
            }
            else
            {
                return new SecondContext();
            }
        }

        static IQueryable<IThing> RunTimeCreatedCollection(DbContext db, int thingType)
        {
            if (thingType == 0)
            {
                return db.Set(typeof(FirstPersonThing)) as IQueryable<IThing>;
            }
            else
            {
                return db.Set<SecondPersonThing>();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing to note is that all this is statically typed so to perform a generic query against different types of objects these objects must have common property signatures and this conceptually is expressed in the IThing interface.

A second thing to note is how the IQueryable is generated.  It is generated by the [`DbContext.Set Method (Type)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679544(v=vs.113).aspx) in the first instance (for the FirstPersonThings), it is generated by the [`DbContext.Set<TEntity> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696521(v=vs.113).aspx) in the second instance.  The first uses a type determined at runtime and requires a cast (but could be useful to use passing types at runtime), the second uses generics and the types are determined at compile time.  There are obviously a number of other ways that this function could work.

Finally the method UpdateRuntimeDeterminedThings works because it uses properties and methods that are shared across the types (either with base types/inheritance or by the implementation of interfaces).

None of this is actually dynamic programming (which is possible using the dynamic type) and I have used the term runtime determined rather than dynamic to describe how this works.

Answer (score 0):

There is a technique in functional programming, called Currying, where you could pass as much parameters as you want, so you are able to access them.
Here is an exemple: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sriram/archive/2005/08/07/448722.aspx

P.S: You could use a currying function to iterate through yours DBContexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use reflection if you want to use 'code' and not sql strings. That's just how C# works... This is how you could do it:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Thing> Things { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Base
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class Box : Base
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

public class Thing : Base
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var db = new TestContext();

        DoIt(GetPropValue(db, "Boxes") as IQueryable<Base>);
        DoIt(GetPropValue(db, "Things") as IQueryable<Base>);
    }

    private static void DoIt(IQueryable<Base> b)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(
            b.Single(t => t.Id == 1).Id);
    }

    private static object GetPropValue(object src, string propName)
    {
        return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName).GetValue(src, null);
    }
}
```

Obviously you can then put the strings in a list etc, whatever you need.